# Laravel Validation - Use array as list of NOT_INs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I want to use th rule:

```
not_in:foo,bar,...
```

But instead of providing the strings like in the example I would like to provide an array.

I know that I can just implode the array to the string but I would like to know if Laravel has an in-built function for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel doesn't have build in functionality for this. But as you said you can simply use implode for this